# Is it a word? Really?

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

Grandpa says:

> show that the following number equals a 5 letter word with multiple meanings
>   (one of them not good)
>
> **I I I X I I X I I X I I I X I I X I I**

I was wondering if that silly thing was a number in the first place!

Hint

> Have you considered a math operator in the number?

Comment: Oh Grandpa......

Comment: It's too long for 5 Roman numerals

Comment: It doesn't seem to be (zbefr pbqr), nor (ovanel). It could be that (gur prageny pncvgny k vf npghnyyl n zhygvcyvpngvba - abgr gung gur fnzr fgevat yvrf ba obgu fvqrf. Pbafvqrevat nyy kf nf zhygvcyvpngvbaf yrnqf gb 699 juvpu frrzf gbb fznyy).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> GROSS
>  If you treat the I's as roman numerals and the X's as multiplication, it multiplies out to 144, which is 1 Gross